# Get facebook albums of a user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to present the albums of a user into a page. This code was working before but now it presents a null page.What im i doing wrong?

```
 $user = $facebook->getUser();
 if ($user) {

 try {

   $albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');

 foreach($albums['data'] as $album) 
 {

$cover = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$albums['id']}/picture? type=album&access_token={$facebook->getAccessToken()}";

echo $album['name'];

echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/cover_photo/picture?type=normal'/>";

}


} 
 catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
 }
 }  else {
$loginUrl = $facebook-$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_photos,friends_photos,user_photo_video_tags'));
echo "<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some minor flaws in your code.

`$album['data']` instead of `$albums['data']` and you already got the url for the cover photo, so you can just use `$cover` for the source.  Here is the reviewed part of code:

```
foreach($albums['data'] as $album) 
{

  $cover = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$album['id']}/picture?type=album&access_token={$facebook->getAccessToken()}";

  echo $album['name'];

  echo "<img src='".$cover."'/>";
}
```